# android xml parsing of sub to subtag and store in hashmap

Tags: android, xml, parsing

Hello all i am new to XML Parsing

I have 1 xml like this

```
 <TAGMAIN>
       <TYPE>THIS IS MY DATA</TYPE>
       <SUCESSCODDE>0</SUCESSCODDE>
       <SUCESSCODDEMESSAGE>Success</SUCESSCODDEMESSAGE>
       <ANOTHERSUBTAG>
          <ENTRY>
             <NUMBER>1234567</NUMBER>
             <MobileNo>12345555555</MobileNo>
             <TOTAL>1.00</TOTAL>
             <TransactionStatus>Success</TransactionStatus>
          </ENTRY>
             <ENTRY>
             <NUMBER>234555</NUMBER>
             <MobileNo>17777777</MobileNo>
             <TOTAL>1.00</TOTAL>
             <TransactionStatus>Success</TransactionStatus>
          </ENTRY>
</ANOTHERSUBTAG>
</TAGMAIN>
```

I have parse it like this

```
 public HashMap<String, String> parse(final Element e) {
          HashMap<String, String> responseMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
          String NAME="";
            final NodeList children = e.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
                final Node n = children.item(i);

                if (n.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    System.out.println(n.getTextContent()+" HERE!!!!!!!!");

                System.out.println("SIZE !!!***"+responseMap.size());
                } else if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    NAME=n.getNodeName();
                    System.out.print(n.getNodeName() + " : ");

                    parse((Element) n);
                    //responseMap.put(n.getNodeName(), n.getTextContent());
                    //System.out.println(n.getTextContent()+" HERE!!!!!!!!");



                }
            }
            return responseMap;
        }
```

Parsing works... now i want to store it like<'NUMBER','123456'>
<'NUMBER','123456'> like tagname and value

or suggests some other way

Please help..
Thanks..

Comment: did you mean attribute? like `<entity number="123456"/>`

Comment: yes how i can get this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [getAttribute(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) method

> Retrieves an attribute value by name.
>
> Parameters name
> The name of the attribute to retrieve.
>
> Returns
>
> The  Attr value as a string, or the empty string if that attribute does not
> have a specified or default value.

For example, `<entity number="134566">`. You would call this method at element of `<entity>`